# How to get the final pasted text in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text, paste

I want to trim a text in a field when the user is writing or paste text on it, the following code works great but has only one problem, when the user selects all the text to replace it with the pasted text or put the cursor to insert the pasted text inside, the code repeats the present value + the new value at the end, How can I fix it?

```
$(document).on('paste', "input[type='text'], textarea", function(e) {

            let val = $(this).val();            
            val = val.trim();
            val = val.replace(/(?:^\s+|\s+?(\s))(\S+)/g, "$1$2");
              val = val.replace(/\s+(\s)$/, "$1");
            $(this).val( val );

    } );
```

I believe what I need to do is to paste normally, get the final pasted text and trim it, but that is the question How to get the final pasted text? Can you help?

Comment: Do your trimming in the `blur` event of the `input` and simply reset the value to the trimmed old value.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't want to use blur, I want the user press CTRL+V where he likes and that text gets trimed.

Comment: You realize that Ctrl+insert and Right Mouse context menu and a host of other possibilities exist for pasting values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the paste event isn't a pipeline that allows you to change the pasting text on the fly. You can access the clipboard, but getting the data from it is a bit challenging as there is [questionable browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) not only for the paste event, but for the clipboardData within said event.

onChange or onBlur are your best bets, as this is a great time to update your values even after a user pastes their value:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea").bind('blur', function(e) {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
} );
```

This will work, whether they type in the whitespaces, or paste them in. If it has to be pasted, then you may want to instead have the above, and a paste event, but the paste event merely sets a shared boolean like "valueIsPasted" to be true, and then you can do the above only when that value is true. I don't love that solution, but unfortunately, the paste support isn't great. On top of that, that still will not work in IE, which doesn't support the paste event.

Update:

Looks like [W3Schools begs to differ](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) on browser support; however, I still feel that onChange or onBlur are your best bets as it will allow you to change the value once the user is done editing the value or done with the control, and definitely work. Check out my [codepen](http://codepen.io/jaxspades/pen/ZBvKXo).

Comment: With your answer I did this: `$(document).on('keyup', "input[type='text'], textarea", function(e) {
  if (isCtrlV( e )) {
   $(this).trigger('change');
  }
  //
 });
 
 $(document).on('change', "input[type='text'], textarea", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
    let val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace(/(?:^\s+|\s+?(\s))(\S+)/g, "$1$2");
    val = val.replace(/\s+(\s)$/, "$1"); 
    $(this).val( val );
   } );`

Comment: @CristianCrishk I suggested `blur` to you and you said you didn't want to use it. My answer below solves your issue and keeps the code running when you said you wanted it to run.

Comment: @Colin Hartwig The paste event is widely supported. That MDN page simply needs updating as it says on the top of it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, that is true, but you didn't answer why "blur" or "change" should be used instead of "paste". As for your current response, delaying due to a timing problem hides the issue without solving it. 

The issue is that the paste event isn't responsible for updating the text box/area; it's just an event that happens and has the event data in it (sometimes, depending upon browser, and the data isn't easy to get as it's keyed based upon type). The better solution is your original response, as it suggested using the events that have the text and can also edit the element itself.

Comment: I did update my answer to state that W3Schools said that it was more widely supported. However, I still feel that it isn't the correct event to use for this workflow. Like I previously said, paste doesn't seem to be a pipeline that allows you to transform the clipboard data, but merely a way to access it and maybe use it. 

While [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#the-paste-action) do allow you to access the data, I noticed that even in Chrome, using the standard specified method of accessing the data, I could not access the data.

Comment: @ColinHartwig You are correct that I didn't explain why `blur` would be better. I didn't do that because at first I left a comment about `blur` and the OP dismissed it and reiterated the desire for `paste`. But, more to the point, my solution does solve the issue, per the requirements of the OP. The internals of `paste` are largely irrelevant. The fact is that the OP's code was running first and the paste was duplicating it second. My solution is no more off-base than using `preventDefault()` when an event's behavior needs modification.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, it's the entire problem to begin with. If you don't research how paste works, how can you fix the problem caused by choosing paste in the first place to do something that it simply doesn't do?

As for preventDefault, I agree, in a lot of cases, people use that to mask an issue, rather than solve it by correcting their event handlers and where they've placed them.

Answer (score -1):

**The issue is that your trim code is running first (causing one copy of the data to be placed in the element) and the paste is happening second (causing a second copy of the data at the end).**

> **If we delay the trim code, the issue is resolved very simply:**

```js
$("#txtInput, textarea").on('paste', function(e) {
  // Store the invocation context (the input element) 
  // because it will change in the setTimeout
  var ctx = this;

  // Wait 1/10th of a second before trimming the data
  // This will allow the paste to complete normally.
  setTimeout(function(){
     $(ctx).val($(ctx).val().trim());            
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" size="40" value="  there are leading and trailing spaces here   ">
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Browser hick ups are bound to cause race conditions this way.